# EditText focus in android

Tags: android, android-edittext

In my application when I click an `EditText`, I have to perform some logic. I have the code. But it is not going into the `click` method.

My code:

```
 EditText des=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.desinc);

 des.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
            {                         
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v)
                {
                    java.lang.System.out.println("Inside click");
                     EditText income=(EditText)findViewById(R.id.editText1);
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                       String inc=income.getText().toString();                    
                    int indexOFdec =  inc.indexOf(".");
                    java.lang.System.out.println("index="+indexOFdec);
                    if(indexOFdec==0)
                    {
                        java.lang.System.out.println("inside index");
                        income.setText(inc+".00");
                    }


                }
            });
```

What am I doing wrong? Help me.

Comment: Whats the problem? your code look right..

Comment: can you explain the mistake or what you want to do??

Comment: I don't know..Its not going into the onclick listener..

Comment: @ bmavus..My problem is that when user clicks editbox,i have to perform some logic as in above code.I tried to print 1 string in the onclick listener,its not printing means my logic inside it also not going to execute..So where i am going wrong???i am scartching my head,because its correct i dont know where i am doing wrong??

Comment: change these (java.lang.System.out.println) with this (Log.v(MESSAGE-TAG,MESSAGE))

I don't think this will solve the problem but sth it is running wrongly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try clicking `EditText` twice because at first instance EditText gets `focus` and after that EditText's `click` event executes. So, if you want your code to execute on first click write your code for focus change of `EditText` using `OnFocusChangeListener()`.

Comment: Thanks Lalit Poptani ..But i used the same code in another screen.It works like charm when i first time click it..

Comment: There the EditText might be already focused so it might be working.

Comment: Onfocus() is working for me..Thats y i accepted this answer.But still i am cofused about onfocus() and onclick().Because as i have already told in another screen it works fine,The edittext is not focussed already,but there it works fine..

Comment: add focus listener for EditText on another Activity and check what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Try overriding onTouch by setting up an onTouchListener in the same way as an onClickListener. Use this code as a reference.

```
EditText dateEdit = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.date);
date.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
       //anything you want to do if user touches/ taps on the edittext box
    }
    return false;
}
});
```

UPDATE(why this behavior):
The first click event focuses the control, while the second click event actually fires the OnClickListener. If you disable touch-mode focus with the android:focusableInTouchMode View attribute, the OnClickListener should fire as expected.

You can also try this: set android:focusableInTouchMode="false" for your EditText box in the xml. See if it works with the existing code.

Comment: Thanks user735675.But what i am going wrong in the above code??

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the above code as i can see, but the default behavior of edittext boxes is to bring up the keyboard first...read my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

You should use `OnFocusChangeListener()`